# React-Ionic set call alert from method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

I created an alert based on the http response of the api. I make a separate `ts` file for login function. What I want is to call or display the alert based on the response. My code works if the function is not separated from the component. But when I do it is not working. Im new to react and ionic.

Login.tsx

```
import login from '../../methods/login';

export const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');
  const [errorAlert, showError] = useState(false);
  const [unauthrozedAlert, showUnauth] = useState(false);

  function loginAuth(){
    login(email,password)
  }

  return (
    <IonPage>
      //forms here

      //forms here

        <IonAlert
          isOpen={errorAlert}
          onDidDismiss={() => showError(false)}
          header={'Alert'}
          message={'Check your inputs'}
          buttons={['OK']}
        />
         <IonAlert
          isOpen={unauthrozedAlert}
          onDidDismiss={() => showUnauth(false)}
          header={'Alert'}
          message={'Account not found'}
          buttons={['OK']}
        />
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

login.ts

```
export default function login(email:string,password:string) {
    const PROXY_URL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    axios.post(PROXY_URL+'http://52.74.70.6/api/auth/login',{
      email:email,
      password:password
    },{ 
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      }).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
    }).catch((err)=>{
      if (err.response.status == 404) {
      console.log(err.response.status);
       errorAlert(true)
      }
      if (err.response.status == 401) {
       showUnauth(true)
      console.log(err.response.status);
      }
    })
}
```

I got `Cannot find name 'errorAlert'.  TS2304`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that i can use native javascript code for alert since jsx wants a component in using toast.

```
export default function login(email:string,password:string) {
    const PROXY_URL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    axios.post(PROXY_URL+'http://52.74.70.6/api/auth/login',{
      email:email,
      password:password
    },{ 
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      }).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
    }).catch((err)=>{
      if (err.response.status == 404) {
      console.log(err.response.status);
       alert404()
      }
      if (err.response.status == 401) {

      console.log(err.response.status);
      }
    })
}
```

I created another function to call based on the status

```
function alert404() {
    const alert = document.createElement('ion-alert');
    alert.header = 'Alert';
    alert.subHeader = 'Subtitle';
    alert.message = 'Account Not Found';
    alert.buttons = ['OK'];

    document.body.appendChild(alert);
    return alert.present();
}
```